# How can I implement a user name availability check on the google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

When someone signs up for my website they must sign up with a unique user name.  My current pseudocode for this is:

```
if(datastore.nameIsAvailable(name)){
    datastore.createUser(name);
}
```

How do I make sure that in between the time when `nameIsAvailable` returns true, and the `createUser` is finished, another instance of my app doesn't create a user with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a query for the name:

```
appuser = AppUser.all().filter('name =', name).get()
if appuser:
  # user already has this name
else:
  # it's all yours!
```

...or better yet have the user's name be the key_name for your `AppUser`:

```
appuser = AppUser.get_by_key(name)
if appuser:
  # user already has this name
else:
  # it's all yours!
```

...and even better:

```
appuser = AppUser.get_or_insert(name)
# appuser is now either the existing user with this name,
# or a new user with this name!
```

Having your name be the entity's key_name means that it will always and forever be unique, and looking up a user by their name will be as fast as possible.

(This is presuming you're using Python, if not, I can add a Java example, but the idea is the same)

Comment: but what prevents the concurrency problem of 2 instances running the code at the same time, and both instances see the name as available because the commit to the datastore didn't happen until after both instances called `AppUser.get_by_key(name)`?

Comment: If you want to check for availability, and take the name if it's available, you can run the two queries in a transaction. That's what get_or_insert(name) does: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py&q=get_or_insert%20package:http://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=870

Comment: I think you should mention that the first two options are not thread safe.  The question is specifically concerned with concurency.

Comment: Excellent point.  Running in a transaction (like get_or_insert() does), an exception will be raised if another user beats you to that username during the transaction.